Which test should I use?
I have a sequence of $x_1,x_2,...,x_m \in \mathbb{R}^n$. And I know each $x_i \sim_{iid} N(0,\sigma^2)$ for some unknown $\sigma>0$. Now I have a bunch of candidates of $\sigma$'s, say, $\sigma_1,\sigma_2,...,\sigma_n.$ And I know $\sigma = \sigma_j$ for some $j \in \{1,2,...,n\}$ but at this moment I do not know what exactly $j$ is.
The problem is: what test should I apply to the sequence of realizations, $\{x_m\}_m$,  to determine/estimate the true candidate's index $j$?

Statistical questions are generally better suited to https://stats.stackexchange.com/ . I would also note that rather a test, your problem is likely better described as "model selection" which should help you find relevant sources and/or ask a more targeted question.

I'll treat this as a maximum likelihood estimation problem with a discrete parameter space, where we'll choose a $\sigma_j^2$ to maximize log likelihood, which is (up to a constant not involving $\sigma^2$)
$$L(\sigma^2) = -\sum_{i=1}^m \frac{x_i^2}{2\sigma^2} -\frac{m}{2}\log\left(\sigma^2\right)
$$
which has unique maximum at $\hat\sigma^2=\frac1m\sum_{i=1}^mx_i^2$ if the parameter space were $\mathbb{R}^+$.
Within the given discrete parameter space,

if $\sigma_j^2=\hat\sigma^2$ for any $j$, the mle is $\hat\sigma^2$.
if all $\sigma_j^2$ are $<\hat\sigma^2$, the mle is $\max_{1\leq j\leq n} \sigma_j^2$;
if all $\sigma_j^2$ are $>\hat\sigma^2$, the mle is $\min_{1\leq j\leq n} \sigma_j^2$;
otherwise, the mle is chosen between the two values that straddle the maximum, $$\ell=\max \lbrace\sigma_j^2: \sigma_j^2<\hat\sigma^2, j=1,2,\dots,n \rbrace \text{ and }
r=\min \lbrace\sigma_j^2: \sigma_j^2>\hat\sigma^2, j=1,2,\dots,n \rbrace. 
$$That is, the mle is
$$\begin{cases}\ell & \text{if } L(\ell)>L(r) \\ 
r & \text{if } L(r)>L(\ell) \\
r\text{ and } \ell & \text{if }L(\ell)=L(r).
\end{cases}
$$

